# Disabling a keyboard key in console

Tags: linux, bash, console, key-mapping

I wrote a script that `dialog` command is vulnerable to `Esc` key, now I want to disable Esc key in console.

**NOTE:** X11 has been not installed in server and `xev` or `xmodmap` doesn't work.

Comment: The console equivalent to `xmodmap` is `loadkeys`. Changing the keymap because of a problem in one application is overkill though. I'd look for an option to tell `dialog` to ignore the Escape key before reaching for that sledgehammer.

Comment: Thanks Wumbley, I'm trying to solve the problem with `loadkeys` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can disable ESC key with `loadkeys` command:

```
$loadkeys
keymaps 0-127
keycode 1 =
press crtl+d
```

Or we can put them in a file and read the file with `loadkeys` command:

```
loadkeys FILE
```

**NOTE:** It just disable ESC key in console.